# How to render huge tables?

Tags: tables, memory

I have the following pipeline to create and render an extremely large truth table: 1) Request logical formula 2) Write LaTeX source 3) Render LaTeX and 4) convert to image.

The equation consists of 16 variables, therefore the table is 514 x 514 (including the border cells) large and marks the cell colours respectively to the formula. However, LaTeX fails to render tables that big. Increasing the memory size is, sadly, not an option.

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
```

So the question becomes: How can I use LaTeX to generate a table, that's big, but has in theory little to no cell content? Does some sort of 'lazy' rendering exist?

Comment: "LaTeX fails to render tables that big." Well, that depends importantly on how you are trying to construct the table. Please do provide more usable information. Incidentally, how are readers supposed to take in the information contained in the table? Just curious.

Comment: Currently I use `tabular` with `513 x '&'` separators per row, for table construction, you can assume that: All cells are equally big, some are coloured, some are empty. If possible, I would like the pipeline to scan a cell, then write to the image, scan next cell, and continue writing. It seems to me that LaTeX tries to render the entire table at once.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your document with LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

On a normal a4 page with 1cm border you can place around 90 cells with a single 1 in each  cell using \footnotesize and a small \tabcolsep of 1pt.  That means that for 514 cells you need a paper width of more than a meter.

Such a huge table overflows the pdftex memory, but with lualatex it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,showframe,paperwidth=115cm,paperheight=180cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\footnotesize \tabcolsep=1pt
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*{514}{l}}
\prg_replicate:nn{514}{\prg_replicate:nn{513}{1&} 1\\}
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I can show only a small part:

[image]

I would reconsider the design.